# Delphi to Java code conversion

Tags: java, delphi, sockets, jpeg, indy

how can i convert the specific code written in Delphi to JAVA

```
  try

    LLine := TMemoryStream.Create;
    IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.WriteLn('atext');

    IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.ReadStream(LLine, -1);

    LLine.Position := 0;  
    LLine.Read(intval, 4); //the server is sending memstream as integer + ajpeg image

    Image1.Picture.Graphic.LoadFromStream(LLine);


  finally
   //free
  end;
```

the above code works perfectly with Delphi , but now i want to create a java client too , but  my own conversion is giving me error(java)

```
 Image image = null ;
 Socket socket = new Socket(someIP, myport);
```

My conversion is

```
      InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
      OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();

         String string = "atext\n";

         byte buffer[] = string.getBytes();
         out.write(buffer);

    in.skip(4); // i don't want the integer

   image = ImageIO.read(in);
```

the server is getting the text atext perfectly , but my java client is having a problem always image is showing a null value (i assigned a breakpoint and checked it );

Comment: is it correct using image = ImageIO.read(in);

Comment: I'm not too savvy with Java, but shouldn't you do something like Image image = ImageIO.read(in);? I mean, you need to define the type of "image" variable, also, put something like System.Out.print( in.size() ); output to the console the number of bytes the server is sending to make sure that the server is sending some bytes.

Comment: no problem, but please edit your question so that others will know without having to read comments also, did you manage to test if the server is actually sending the image bytes?

Comment: P.S. what are value should the integer(those 4 bytes) hold? I assume the size of the image?

Comment: @DorinDuminica No integer(those 4 bytes) they are some other information(not the size of the image) needed for some other task.

Comment: can you call in.available() to make sure that there are more than 0 bytes?

Comment: @DorinDuminica , it is always telling 8192 (even with different jpg images)

Comment: Now we're getting somewhere, please look at the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4478438/why-does-java-read-random-amounts-from-a-socket-but-not-the-whole-message and use the copy from inputstream into the byte buffer stream, basically the inputstream uses a 8KB buffer

Comment: Is that means that maximum amount we can get transferred is 8K bytes

Comment: not quite, it means that the minimum size the buffer is going to return when calling .available() is going to be 8KB even if the "real" data size is 1 byte

Comment: You need to [check the value returned by skip](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#skip%28long%29).

Answer (score 0):

The [ImageIO.read(InputStream input)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read%28java.io.InputStream%29) documentation says:

> If no registered ImageReader claims to be able to read the resulting
>   stream, null is returned.

So the null value seems to be normal in this case. Have you checked that a matching ImageReader is **registered**? (For example by loading an existing, valid reference image file)

Comment: How did you verify that the ImageReader is registered? Do other ways to load an image of the same type work fine? for example using [ImageIO.read(URL input)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read%28java.net.URL%29)

Comment: i have already assigned an image and it showing the image  , but after  assigning the inputstream it is getting blank

Comment: then I would try to save the image data to a local file first and check if it is a valid image file (using a normal viewer app)